# space at the beginning of value are not working

Tags: regex

I have the following regex and I want to allow to start with one space(not mandtory),
How should I do that ?I try with the following and its not working

```
@"\s^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*$"
```

Comment: `@"^\s?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*$"` - notice the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `\s` *after* your starting caret (`^`). e.g.

```
^\s?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*$
```

Note I also added a quantifier (`?`) to `\s` to say "this can appear 0 or 1 time".

Also, the class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be replaced with `\w` (which is the same thing). So, the shortened pattern then becomes:

```
^\s?\w+\s*$
```

Meaning:

```
^             # start of string
  \s?         # 0 or 1 whitespace character ([ \f\n\r\t\v])
  \w+         # 1 or more of the following: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _
  \s*         # 0 or more whitespace characters ([ \f\n\r\t\v])
$             # end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
@"^\s?\w+\s*$"
```

- You need to place start enchor `^` before optional `\s?`
- Also note I have used `\w` which is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

what about @" ?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*$"